# How do I enable GPS Automatically once the app logged in IONIC 3?

Tags: angular, geolocation, ionic3, gps, fleet

How can I enable GPS automatically without having the notifaction allow or deny programmatically through ionic 3, It's just because some users may click deny by mistake i don't want to happen, so if there's any possiblity in ionic 3 to turn on GPS once the app logged and turn off automatically once I logged out ?

Any help
Thanks.

Comment: You can't activate the GPS without the user permission.

Comment: Its not possible. User consent is mandatory to gain the access to any Hardware related.

Comment: Thanks for your replies but in this example they are able to do it i guess, but its Ionic1 https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-programmatically-enable-and-disable-gps-in-ionic-framework/87030/3

Comment: Is there any possiblities as like this in IONIC 3?

Comment: @guru check this link "https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/diagnostic/"  with `isLocationEnabled()` and `requestLocationAuthorization(mode)` method